# Unit test Service and Mock Autogenerated WCF Client proxy

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, wcf, mocking

I'm referencing an Auto-generated WCF Client in a Service.

```
//Autogenerated Service client
public partial class ServiceClient : 
    System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IService>, IService 
{
    //...
}
//Autogenerated Interface Client
public interface IService {
    //...
}
```

In the following manner:

```
public MyService{

    public IExternalWsClientFactory ExternalWsClientFactory {get; set; }

    public void MyMethod(){
        using (var wsCliente = ExternalWsClientFactory.ServiceClient())
        { 
            //... 
        }
    }
}

public class ExternalWsClientFactory : IExternalWsClientFactory
{
    public ServiceClient ServiceClient()
    {
        var wsClient = new ServiceClient();
        return wsClient;
    }
}
```

I reference the implementation because **I want to use the `using` statement** to dispose resources at the end of the code block. And because the `IDisposable` is under `ClientBase` and the interface is not partial.

**My problem is that I want to mock `ServiceClient` (I already mock External `WsClientFactory`) but since I use the implementation I'm having hard trouble to do this.**

NOTE: the auto-generated method `ServiceClient` in the implementation is not `virtual`.

Comment: The class is partial. the interface is not. create your own interface that derives from the original interface and extends it with `IDisposable`. extend the partial class with your custom interface and now you should be able to use your extended interface with `using` statement

Comment: Oh boy! I wished it is a lazy way to do this. I have 11 Web Service Referencia. Thanks @Nkosi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class is partial. The interface is not.

Create your own interface that derives from the original interface and extends it with `IDisposable`.

```
public interface IServiceClient: ICommunicationObject, IService, IDisposable { }
```

extend the partial class with your custom interface

```
public partial class ServiceClient : IServiceClient { }
```

and now you should be able to use your extended interface with `using` statement

```
public class ExternalWsClientFactory : IExternalWsClientFactory {
    public IServiceClient ServiceClient() {
        var wsClient = new ServiceClient();
        return wsClient;
    }
}
```